# please help sinusoidal function what does it mean finding the origin formula

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

This chapter was introducing the basic sinusoidal forms [image]
I did not understand what, in the first picture, they meant by "choosing the origin". I thought that meant that t=0 but the formulas in the 1st picture don't appear to make t=0. So have the formulas made x=0? But that doesn't look like the case. So then, what does choosing the origin mean? I can only see they removed the initial phase angle from original sinusoidal SHM formulas, thus converting them into the four ones above. But I am not aware of the circumstances/conditions that necessitate the removal of the initial angle phase from the formulas. The textbook is Cambridge Mathematics, specifically dealing with physics applications.